# Initial value of calloc, when using with a struct

Tags: c, struct, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

I am trying to write a very simple hash table by using following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 10

typedef struct {
    char *first_name;
    char *last_name;
} Employee;

typedef struct {
    Employee *table;
} Hashtable;

void initHashtable(Hashtable *ht) {
    ht->table = (Employee *)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(Employee));
}

int hashKey(char *key) {
    int length = strlen(key);
    return length % SIZE;
}

void put(Hashtable *ht, Employee emp, char *key) {
    int hashedKey = hashKey(key);
    ht->table[hashedKey] = emp;
}
```

And I can insert elements by doing:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    Employee e1;
    e1.first_name = "John";
    e1.last_name = "Doe";

    Hashtable ht;

    initHashtable(&ht);
    put(&ht, e1, "Doe");

    return 0;
}
```

But I want to modify the "put" function, so when I try to insert something, it will check if that index is empty or not. If empty then return some message, if not then insert on that index. Similar to:

```
void put(Hashtable *ht, Employee emp, char *key) {
    int hashedKey = hashKey(key);

    if (ht->table[hashedKey] != 0) {
        printf("Employee is in that index!\n");
    } else {
        ht->table[hashedKey] = emp;
    }
}
```

But this "if statement" is not working. So, i tried with both 0 and NULL. Then I tried with casting like:

```
if(ht->table[hashedKey] != (Employee *)0)
```

and

```
if(ht->table[hashedKey] != (Employee)0)
```

Nothing is working. My question is I knew calloc initializes with 0, zero. Then in case of struct what do calloc initializes with?

Comment: I recommend you have your `table` member being an array of *pointers*. First of all it makes it easier to solve your problem since an empty entry will be a `NULL` pointer. Secondly it also makes it easier to solve another problem: Hash collisions, using e.g. linked lists or similar.

Comment: Also, [in C you should not cast the result of `malloc` (or related function like `calloc`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: Please provide an [mcve].

Comment: I'm attempting to compile your code, and I'm seeing `invalid operands to binary expression ('Employee' and 'int')` for that comparison. Perhaps that's an issue?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for your suggestion, using array of pointers is a great idea. But still I want to know what do calloc initializes when using with struct?

Comment: The `calloc` function is equivalent to calling `malloc` followed by `memset` to set all bytes to `0`.

Comment: @WernerHenze thanks, didn't knew about that. Will keep in mind.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks dude, and thanks for the cast link.

Comment: The only clue you have given about what is not working is “But this "if statement" is not working.” When asking about a problem, you should **always** state **what undesired behavior is occurring** and **what desired behavior is expected instead**. When you say the “if statement” is not working, we do not know whether you mean the compiler is giving you an error message while compiling or whether the program is running but the `if` statement appears to be taking a branch other than the desired one. You should provide a [Minimal Verifiable Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But this "if statement" is not working.

By "not working", I presume you mean "does not compile".

> So, i tried with both 0 and
>   NULL. Then I tried with casting like:
>
> ```
> if(ht->table[hashedKey] != (Employee *)0)
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> if(ht->table[hashedKey] != (Employee)0)
> ```
>
> Nothing is working.

Your compiler will be emitting diagnostic messages explaining *why* it rejects your code.  Such diagnostics can sometimes be cryptic, but surely the complaints about datatype should lead you to ask yourself the question "what are the types involved here?".  Nevertheless, we can help:

- `ht->table[hashedKey]` has type `Employee` (a structure, not a pointer to one).  This is probably the most important one for your purposes, but let's go on ....
- `0` is a constant of type `int`, which also serves as a null pointer constant (its type notwithstanding).
- `(Employee *) 0` is a null pointer of type `Employee *`.
- `(Employee) 0` is an invalid expression.  It has no type, because it is not valid to cast an `int` to a structure type such as `Employee`.

Structure types such as `Employee` are not valid operands of the `!=` operator (or of the `==` operator, or of most others).  This is your main problem.  Even if you produced an `Employee` representation with all bits zero, which can be done in various ways, you *still* could not directly compare it for (in)equality with `ht->table[hashedKey]` via any of C's operators.  Even if structures *were* comparable, however, it would not make sense to compare a structure with a pointer of any type, as your first example tries to do.

> My question is I knew calloc initializes with 0,
>   zero. Then in case of struct what do calloc initializes with?

This does not appear to have anything to do with your problem, but since you asked, `calloc` initializes the space it allocates to all bits zero.  For integer types (including among the members of a structure), this is a representation of 0.  For other types, including pointer types, the language does not specify what this representation signifies.

To check whether two structures are equal, you need to compare them member by member.  In your particular case, however, you don't really need to compare structures, you just need to check the members of *one* structure.  However, because a pointer value with all bits zero is not necessarily a null pointer, yet may well not point to anything, it is not safe to compare a pointer value allocated via `calloc` to *anything*.  With that being the case, and your `Employee` structure not having any non-pointer members, `calloc`'s memory initialization does not gain you anything useful.

Instead, you should manually initialize each hash table element:

```
void initHashtable(Hashtable *ht) {
    ht->table = malloc(SIZE, sizeof(Employee));
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        ht->table[i].first_name = NULL;
        ht->table[i].last_name = NULL;
    }
}
```

Having done that, you can check whether a given slot in the table has been assigned by checking the members:

```
if (ht->table[hashedKey].first_name != NULL || ht->table[hashedKey].last_name != NULL) // ...
```

Because null pointers evaluate to false in boolean context and non-null pointers (even invalid ones) evaluate to true, you can abbreviate that as

```
if (ht->table[hashedKey].first_name || ht->table[hashedKey].last_name) // ...
```

... if you prefer.  Either version tells you that the table element has been assigned.

Answer (score 5):

> My question is I knew calloc initializes with 0, zero. Then in case of struct what do calloc initializes with?

`calloc` has absolutely no idea how you will use the memory. It just gives you the amount you requested with all bits set to zero. Look at the prototype for it:

```
void * calloc(size_t num, size_t size)
```

The parameters `num` and `size` is the *only* information that `calloc` has.

Comment: Is there any way to check if an index/location has any value other than zero?

Comment: @drmirk Ehm, yes of course. You read all the values and compare them to zero.